# How to fill up cells with column labels using excel function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Esteemed members, I want to fill up cells with column labels eg.AA,AB,AC ....AZ, BA, BB etc. However, I was looking at using functions with drag down feature to achieve this.I have tried by trial and the function I got is very long to say least.If I save the excel file with these formulas, the excel size will be huge.

Does anyone knows of any more efficient way without sacrificing too much of file size?

Much thnx in advanced.
Truly

This is the function that I managed to scrambled by trial:
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(A1)=1,IF(IF((2*(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)))-32)/53<>4,IF((2*(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)))-32)/37=4,1,0),1)=1,IF((2*(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)))-32)/53<>4,IF((2*(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)))-32)/37=4,CHAR(ROW($A$65)),CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))+1)))),CHAR(ROW($A$97)))&IF((2*(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)))-32)/53<>4,IF((2*(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)))-32)/37=4,CHAR(ROW($A$65)),CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))+1)))),CHAR(ROW($A$97))),IF((2*(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)))-32)/53<>4,IF((2*(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)))-32)/37=4,CHAR(ROW($A$65)),CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))+1)))),CHAR(ROW($A$97)))),IF(IF((2*(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)))-32)/53<>4,IF((2*(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)))-32)/37=4,1,0),1)=1,CHAR(CODE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)))+1)&IF(LEN(A1)=2,"",CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&IF(CODE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),1))=90,ROW($A$65),ROW($A$97))))))&CHAR(ROW($A$97)),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)&IF((2*(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)))-32)/53<>4,IF((2*(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)))-32)/37=4,CHAR(ROW($A$65)),CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))+1)))),CHAR(ROW($A$97))))),"")

Comment: So what exactly is it you want? You want to display the current column letters in your headers? Can you show some sample data with what you have, what you done and expected results. Look here [ask] and here [mcve]

Comment: Yes.That's the actual plan.And this is the test file.."expirebox.com/files/50fbd086c13a61a5ce09c4cc1da2a474.xlsx" .Basically the formula supposed to return the next column letter of the alphabets I input in cell A1. So if I drag the formula down, it should give a list of column letters in running sequence. for example, AA,AB,AC and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment you want to get a running sequence in alfabetical order based on the letter in cell `A1`(sorry but I'm not downloading any file, while you should have updated your question more appropriately).

Hereby a short formula that should do just that:

```
=LEFT(ADDRESS(1,ROW(A1),4,TRUE),(ROW(A1)>26)+1)
```

Put this is cell `A1` and drag it down. This will start with "A" but when you would change `ROW(A1)` to say `ROW(A3)` it will start with "C".

If you want to extend beyond "ZZ" then you have to change around the formula a bit to:

```
=LEFT(ADDRESS(1, ROW(A1), 4, TRUE), (ROW(A1)>26)+(ROW(A1)>702)+1)
```

Another formula you could use in cell `A1`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,ROWS(A$1:A1),4),1,"")
```

Also here, if you dont want to start of with "A", you could change `A$1:A1` to `A$1:A3` for example to start of with "C". This formula works beyond "ZZ" already.

Comment: Thanks JvdV.. This helps. 
Was glad I came here.
Cheers.